# Call another powershell pass parameter use different creds

Tags: powershell

I want to call another secondary powershell script from within my primary powershell script.  I want to pass it a parameter from the primary script, the secondary script needs the username parameter, I want to pass to it, from the primary, and then have the secondary script Im calling use different credentials.  I think I might be able to use invoke-command, I just dont know all the syntax, anyone able to post some examples of what I want to accomplish, and then I'll fill in the blanks if need be?
Thanks in advance!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, thanks to Trevor Sullivan for pointing me in the right direction.
I ended up just putting my second ps1 file into a scriptblock, and running it as a job, and passing it the arguments from the main script, like this

```
$job = Start-Job -scriptblock {
 param ($username)
 some code to run against the variable that was passed in
 } -Args $target -credential $Cred
```

$target being the variable I want to pass to my scriptblock
$username being the parameter that the scriptblock accepts
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your secondary script looks like this:

```
param (
    [string] $Username = $args[0]
)
Write-Output -InputObject $Username;
```

You can use the `Start-Process` cmdlet to launch the script with alternate credentials.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential;
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList '"c:\path\to my\file.ps1" -Username "UsernameGoesHere!"' -Credential $Credential;
```

Or you can use the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath 'c:\path\to my\script.ps1' -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList "UsernameGoesHere!";
```

Comment: Where do I specify the parameter I am passing it from the primary script??  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I will try that, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Okay, I just updated it again, since I noticed you edited your question. It looks like you need a `Username` parameter.